# Creating a custom Spark RDD in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Is it possible to extend Spark's RDDs in Python to add custom operators? If it's not possible, how can one wrap Scala code for a class that extends an RDD, such as the one here:
http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/extending-spark-api/

Edit: I am trying to create a new RDD, say PersonRDD and add a set of new operators on the PersonRDD, ex. PersonRDD.computeMedianIncome(). According to the link below, it is not trivial to do that in Python. However, since it's an old thread, I was wondering whether there were any new updates on that. If not, I would like to use Scala to do it, but I am not sure how to call the class  from Python using Py4J ( mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201308.mbox/…)

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Mandy

Answer (score 4):

Computing exact median in a distributed environment takes some effort so lets say you want something like square all values in a RDD. Let's call this method `squares` and assume it should work as follows:

```
assert rdd.squares().collect() == rdd.map(lambda x: x * x).collect()
```

#### 1. Modify `pyspark.RDD` definition:

```
from pyspark import RDD

def squares(self):
    return self.map(lambda x: x * x)

RDD.squares = squares
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
assert rdd.squares().collect() == [1, 4, 9]
```

Note: If you modify class definition every instance will get access to the `squares`.

#### 2. Create RDD subclass:

```
class RDDWithSquares(RDD):
    def squares(self):
        return self.map(lambda x: x * x)

rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
rdd.__class__ = RDDWithSquares # WARNING: see a comment below
```

Assigning a class is a dirty hack so  in practice you should create a RDD in a proper way (see for example [context.parallelize](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/492dca3a73e70705b5d5639e8fe4640b80e78d31/python/pyspark/context.py#L374) implementation).

#### 3. Add method to an instance

```
import types

rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
# Reusing squares function defined above
rdd.squares = types.MethodType(squares, rdd)
```

#### Disclaimer

First of all I haven't tested any of these long enough to be sure there no hidden problems there.

Moreover I don't think it is really worth all the fuss. Without static type checking it is really hard to find any benefits and you can obtain a similar result using functions, currying, and [`pipes`](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.pipe) in a much cleaner way.

```
from toolz import pipe
pipe(
    sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3]),
    squares,
    lambda rdd: rdd.collect())
```

Comment: Thanks @zero323. I would've have liked to cleanly inherit form RDD, like one can do in Scala or Java, rather than hack the solution. Solution 1 won't work since users can call new operators on wrong type. 2 does not work with subclasses of RDD, ex.: newAPIHadoopFile, but could work for me...
Thanks again for taking the time to suggest solutions

Comment: Well, you have to remember a couple of things. Typing discipline in Python is quite different from Scala and Python RDDs are not parametrized by type. From Scala perspective every Python RDD looks like `RDD[Any]`.  Because of that it is your responsibility to call methods only an applicable methods. Something like `sc.parallelize(range(3)).groupByKey()` is clearly not meaningful and will fail when transformation is executed, but there is nothing wrong on a type level.

Comment: Unlike in Scala you can modify existing class on the runtime. No implicit conversion hell and we know that "_Explicit is better than implicit_". If you add a method there is still nothing wrong with types. The only it says is that depending on a state of the instance it may be valid to call this method. From a conceptual point of view it is probably the closest thing you can get to the Scala implicit methods. Still, I think that piping function calls is much safer, more Pythonic, and works just as well if want to create DSL on top of Spark.

Comment: It makes total sense. You obviously have much more experience with Spark than I do, so I will consider the piping example as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and while I haven't tested the full functionality of normal RDDs on my extended version so far it is working as expected. It does require some work and I'm not sure if this is the best solution but what I'm doing is just extending the RDD class, reimplement the methods that return a new RDD by passing them in a constructor of the new Class and add methods to the class. Here is a short part of the code:

```
from pyspark.rdd import RDD, PipelinedRDD

class CustomRDD(RDD):
    def __init__(self, rdd, first=True):
        if first:
            rdd = custom_parser(rdd)
        self._jrdd = rdd._jrdd
        self.is_cached = rdd.is_cached
        self.is_checkpointed = rdd.is_checkpointed
        self.ctx = rdd.ctx
        self._jrdd_deserializer = rdd._jrdd_deserializer
        self._id = rdd._id
        self.partitioner = rdd.partitioner

    def mapPartitionsWithIndex(self, f, preservesPartition=False):
        return CustomRDD(PipelinedRDD(self, f, preservesPartition), False)

    def union(self, other):
        return WebtrendsRDD(super(WebtrendsRDD, self).union(other), False)

    def custom_method(self):
        return CustomRDD(self.filter(lambda x: x.has_property()), False)
```

The mapPartitionsWithIndex method is called by a lot of other RDD functionality so that covers a lot, but there are a lot of other methods that you have to wrap with your own constructor to keep getting back your own CustomRDD like I did with union.